# Concatenate sublists in R

Tags: r, list

I have a foreach loop that generates a list of lists as follows:

```
library(doParallel)

foo = foreach(i = 1:3) %do% {
  x = rnorm(100)
  y = rnorm(100)
  m = lm(y~x)
  m2 = lm(y~1)
  retRes = list('a' = m, 'b' = m2)
  return(retRes)
}
```

The results look like:

```
> foo
[[1]]
[[1]]$a

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   -0.06506     -0.00199  


[[1]]$b

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
   -0.06529  



[[2]]
[[2]]$a

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    -0.1366       0.1934  


[[2]]$b

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
     -0.125
```

etc.

I'd like to concatenate the list so that I have something that looks like

```
list(a = list of models "m"; b = list of models "m2")
```

I can't use the do.call/rbind trick described in one of the suggestions below because the element data type is not primitive.  Thoughts?

Comment: Please make a *reproducible* example. You can use `dput()`.

Comment: can you provide dput output fo your sample data? Thanks

Comment: Please also show your expected output.

Comment: Done - made changes and added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionnend in the comment an example would help, and I am not sure what you mean by "with top-level elements of $a and $b" but one thing that may do what you want is "do.call".

I suppose that your original dataset has been created using something as follow:

```
> your_dataset=list(list(a=3,b=5),list(a=3,b=5),list(a=3,b=5))
> print(your_dataset)
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 3

[[1]]$b
[1] 5


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 3

[[2]]$b
[1] 5


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] 3

[[3]]$b
[1] 5
```

If that is the case and what you want is somehow what I think you need you just have to do:

```
> do.call("rbind.data.frame",your_dataset)
     a b
[1,] 3 5
[2,] 3 5
[3,] 3 5
```

you can then access both column as list using dataframe notaion "$":

```
> df=do.call("rbind.data.frame",your_dataset)
> df$a
[1] 3 3 3
> df$b
[1] 5 5 5
```

[EDIT] if the original dataset is made of non primitive data and we want a list of list and not an actual `data.frame`:

```
> header=c(a="a",b="b")
> new_list=lapply(header,function(h)lapply(your_dataset,"[[",h))
> new_list$a
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 3

> new_list$b
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

You can eventually create `header` directly by looking at the names of your initial list:

```
> header=unlist(unique(lapply(your_dataset,names)))
> names(header)=header
```

Comment: You seem to have not copied over the correct `$` example code.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will work, since in actual example my values are not numeric but rather s3 class objects.  So I can't use rbind, since I don't believe data frames can store non-primitive data types.  How would I modify this to create a list of lists called "a" and "b"?

Comment: in that case you could then use lapply twice, a bit less elegant, but with a vector `header=c(a="a",b="b")` then you can do: `new_list=lapply(header,function(h)lapply(your_dataset,"[[",h))`  
(I edited my answer with this version of the solution)

Comment: You are a genius.  I can barely even understand this usage.  I've been using R for 15 years and can't quite come to grips with the arcana of this type!

Comment: great if it works! i didn't see you updated your question with an example, I'll udpate my answer using your `foo` when I have time, but it should be ok with `lm()` output too

Comment: I've confirmed that it works.  I keep forgetting that I can apply "[[" as a function recursively.